# Check if pg_prepare was already executed

Tags: postgresql, php-7.4

Is there a way to check if `pg_prepare` already executed and remove it from the session?

Seems like `pg_close` doesn't remove prepared statement from the session. Kind of seems like a bug in php, but maybe I'm missing something or maybe there is a workaround.

```php
public static function readSubdomains($dcName, $filter = null) {
// ...
        $conn = pg_pconnect($connectionString);
// ...

        $result = pg_prepare($conn, "subdomains", "SELECT subdomain
            from tenants
            where $where
            order by 1 asc
        ");
        $result = pg_execute($conn, "subdomains", $params);

// ...

        pg_close($conn);
}
```

Second call to `readSubdomains` shows a warning like this:

```
Warning: pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR: prepared expression "subdomains" already exists in inc/TestHelper.php on line 121
```

Comment: Try running a `pg_query("DEALLOCATE subdomains");` before `pg_prepare(..)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you make an answer from your comment I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Always check the official manuals for this sort of stuff.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-prepared-statements.html

Oh - if `pg_close` isn't dropping prepared statements then it isn't closing the connection. You might have some connection pooling involved.